# How to add a style if the parent has a sibling with a specific id using only CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

Given this code below, how can I add a border color in the input element if the parent has a sibling with this ID "message"?

```
<div>
  <input class="red"/>
</div>
<div id="message">
  Error message
</div>
```

I can't use JS in this case, only CSS. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) with the selector `div:has( + div#message) > input`:

```css
div:has( + div#message) > input {
  border: solid 2px red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="red" />
</div>
<div id="message">
  Error message
</div>
```

Comment: Note that at this time Firefox supports :has only if the browser has been set to use it.

Comment: @AHaworth Very true, however if you read the mozilla dev chats its implementation is supposed to be any day now